# What is this boolean operation? `expression * boolean`

Tags: c++, boolean-operations

I saw a problem where we had to find the wage. If the hours are less than 40 we pay regular wage ($100/hr) if there is overtime we give 1.5 times the original pay ($150/hr).

The challenge was to solve it without if-else/loops/or ternary operations.

It was solved like this

```
int hours = /*some_number*/;
int wage = (100*hours) + (50*(hours-40))*(hours>40);
```

This code works.
`(hours>40)` returns `1` if hours is greater than 40 and returns `0` if it is less. 
I understand that it is some kind of boolean operation, but how does it work and what is this called exactly.

Comment: Are you asking what `>` does?

Comment: There's not much more to it; `bool` values convert to `0` and `1` in C++.

Comment: Multiplying by a boolean is conceptually similar to `&&` or `if` - if it's 1, you get your number. otherwise you get zero.

Comment: `hours > 40` returns true `1` on success and false `0` on failure.

Comment: What do you want from the expression `hours > 40` to return?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I know what boolean operation is, but this form is unfamiliar to me. I am guessing it has something to do with logic gates but I'm not sure. If I do `(hours?40)` to check if `hours ==40`, it does not work here but the inequality does.

Comment: Value of type `bool` is (implicitly) convertible to `int` and vice versa.

Comment: Why would `(hours?40)` work? There is no `?` operator. But `(hours == 40)` would work.

Comment: What *exactly* you don't understand? *"this form is unfamiliar to me"* It's just `a > b`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to do it is straight-forward:

```
int hours = /*some_number*/;
int wage = 100*hours;
if (hours > 40) wage += 50 * (hours-40);
```

To squeeze it to a single expression, the example takes advantage of the fact that a boolean is either 1 or 0. So `x*some_bool` evaluates to either `x` or `0`.

In your case, if `(hours > 40)` then

```
(50*(hours-40))*(hours>40) == (50*(hours-40)) * 1 == 50*(hours-40)
```

otherwise it is `0`.

```
(50*(hours-40))*(hours>40) == (50*(hours-40)) * 0 == 0
```

In general it is less readable to write code this way. The only valid uses IMO are in advanced algebraic transformations used in cryptography or complexity theory.

Answer (score 0):

Well you basically answered your question. The `(hours > 40)` returns `1` if hours is greater than 40 and returns `0` otherwise.

Maybe more tricky part is the fact that this boolean result is then converted to int [implicitly](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) before being multiplied by overtime payment, but that is out of the scope of the question.

So the whole code could be indeed expanded in this way

```
int hours = /* something */
int wage = 0;
int overtime = hours - 40;
if (hours > 40) {
  wage = 100*hours + 50*overtime;
}
else {
  wage = 100*hours
}
```